AWS EC2 Windows Key pair (Windows, LOST)
I am a complete AWS noob.
I created a project on an instance and have an sdk that is tied to the instance, of which the key I have misplaced.
I have followed the advice that I saw on here and stopped the instance, detached the volume, created a temporary instance, reattached the volume to the new instance. But I dont know how, or where to find a location to change the authorized keys
\Users\Administrator\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Credentials is empty

this might help https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/openssh/openssh_keymanagement
